# Construct list of maps from a csv in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have the following variable

```
variable "whitelisted_ips" {   
    default = "xx.xxx.xx.x/21,xxx.xx.xxx.x/20"
}
```

I use this some places where a list of CIDRS is needed using the following

```
cidr_blocks = ["${split(",", var.whitelisted_ips)}"]
```

That all works fine.

I want to reuse these values and end up with the following structure (expressed as JSON to give you an idea)

```
waf_ips = [
    { value = "xx.xxx.xx.x/21", type="IPV4"},
    { value = "xxx.xx.xxx.x/20", type="IPV4"},
]
```

So I am looking to create a list of maps from the string (the IPV4 is hardcoded and repeats on every line).

If I feed my current JSON to an aws_waf_rule and treat it as a list it succeeds, but I'd rather not repeat the data in the tfvars file as its the same and I'd like to reuse that string separated list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so having learned more and read more it turns out you can do this with a null resource for static data so.

```
locals {
  cidr_blocks = ["xxx.xxx.xxx/23", "xxx.xxx.xxx/23", "xxx.xxx.xxx/23"]
}

resource "null_resource" "cidr_map_to_protocol" {
  count = "${length(local.cidr_blocks)}"

  triggers = {
    value     = "${element(local.cidr_blocks, count.index)}"
    type      = "IPV4"
  }
}

output "mapped_cidr_to_protocol" {
  value = "${null_resource.cidr_map_to_protocol.*.triggers}"
}
```

this will not work for a computed resource unfortunately.